# Nvidia drivers (normal vs game ready)

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I wanted to update my nvidia driver but I can't find anymore  "normal" nvidia driver, just "game ready" drivers.

What is game ready driver?
Should I install it? 
Where can I find "normal" nvidia drivers?
What is the difference between nomal and game ready drivers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Ramhound told me in the comments:

> Nvidia has introduce updated drivers, for new software releases, for
>   years under the term "GameReady", the exact same driver they send to
>   their partners that come with Nvidia GPUs and the exact same driver
>   they publish to Microsoft to be updated via Windows Update. The only
>   difference is Nvidia publishes newer versions faster then either of
>   those channels. There is no difference at all between the actual
>   performance unless a specific version, increases the performance, with
>   a specific piece of software