# NVIDIA display driver, Windows 10: Install most recent GEFORCE GAME READY DRIVER in addition to most recent device manager update?

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, device-manager, nvidia

I know from [Nvidia drivers (normal vs game ready)](https://superuser.com/questions/1033494/nvidia-drivers-normal-vs-game-ready) that "Game Ready" and the driver you get sent with the package are just different names of the same driver.

After installing the driver on the CD, I have updated "NVIDIA GeForce GT 710" in the Windows 10 device manager using [right-click>update driver] on the card, leading to:

- [Properties>driver>driver details] "Version 2.1 NVIDIA Build_224"
- [Properties>driver] driver version: "26.21.14.3200"
- [Properties>driver] driver date: 2019.07.24

Should I install "GEFORCE GAME READY DRIVER" from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/162105/en-us in addition to this, which extracts to `C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\451.67\Win10-DCH_64\International` and which is much more recent, from 2020.7.09?

("Question B": And if so, why is the device manager not updating to the most recent state?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should update to the latest driver. You could've installed it in the first place too.

There was no need to install one from the CD, as you've updated it using Windows Update anyway.

> why is the device manager not updating to the most recent state?

I'd guess NVIDIA doesn't want to spend their time on keeping an outdated, underpowered GPU up-to-date through Windows Update. They probably have to go through a Microsoft's certification process for every driver and device. With a more modern graphics card you'd probably get a fresher driver version (although not necessarily the latest one, because they tend to be included in Windows Update with a delay).